# Destructor for a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, memory-management

The full code is located here: https://gist.github.com/4521540

It's a dummy `List` in C++. My concern is with freeing up memory. 
It doesn't crash when I run my code. It looks like my `if/else` covers everything.

1. It starts by deleting the second item if there is. That's what the while loop does.
2. If there is only one present (or left with one), delete `startNode`.

`startNode` is a pointer points to the first item in the list.
`endNode` always points to the last item in the list.

Am I deleting the pointer or the underlying object?

I do mostly Python. Last time I wrote a serious C++ homework was about 2 years ago in my algorithm class so I really can't remember everything off my head.

```
~List()
{        
    // there is at least one item
    if(startNode != 0)
    {   
        // release memory starting from the second item
        ListNode *current, *soon;
        current = this->startNode->next;
        while(current != 0)  // if there are at least two items
        {
            /* When there is no more items after current,
             * delete current and leave.
             * Otherwise, free up current and move on to
             * the next item.
             */
            if(current->next != 0)
            {
                soon = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = soon;
            }
            else
            {
                delete current;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    delete this->startNode;
    delete this->endNode;
}
```

Also, do I need to delete the `myList` in my main program? I think when I exit the program, the destructor is automatically called.

Comment: You also might want to read up on smart pointers. You can protect against memory leaks and double deletes by using `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Do you have a test suite for this?  And have you run it under Valgrind (or other memory checker of your choice)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to answer your questions about new/delete: Everything you `new`, you must `delete` at some point, or you leak memory. When you `new`, you are given a pointer to the object that has been allocated. Similarly, when you use `delete`, you must use a pointer to that same object, and the memory that was allocated will be freed. After doing this, the pointer will be pointing at freed memory and you should not `delete` this again. It doesn't matter where you use `new`, in `main()` or otherwise, you need to `delete` it at some point.

Now to your code: Your code will double-delete either the first node when the list size is 1, or the last node, when the list size is greater than 1. Double deletes cause undefined behaviour including crashes.

Let's look at list of size 1 first. Your while loop won't be entered, and you basically skip down to the end where you do

```
delete this->startNode;
delete this->endNode;
```

Since startNode and endNode should both be pointing to the only node in the list, it will get deleted twice!

If you have a list of more items, the loop will delete every item except the first. Then the last two statements occur. In this case, `this->endNode` will be the original end of the list (since you never alter it here) and so it will be deleted twice.

Here is a simpler version that just deletes every node, starting from the first.

```
~List
{
    ListNode* current = startNode;
    ListNode* next;

    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: That *can* be shortened: `for (auto p = startNode; p;) delete std::exchange(p, p->next);`

Answer (score -2):

A cleaner way would be to go iteratively through the list.

I would do something like:

```
~List()
{   
    if(startNode == NULL)
       return;

    if(startNode->Next != 0)
    {   
         delete this->startNode->Next;
    }
    delete this->startNode;
}
```

This will go through your list, and `startNode->Next` will be the new startNode (this), thus it should delete the whole list just fine.

Comment: You meant `while (startNode->next != 0)`?Also, correct me if I am wrong: I only need to provide a destructor if there's `new` in the class/struct implementation, right? Do I need to delete anything in `main`? Thanks.

Comment: This code will only delete the first and second node. Even if you change the `if` to a `while`, you would need to add a temporary variable in there to keep track of the `next` before deleting it, and then re-assigning startNode.

Comment: It depends what type startNode is actually. I would do it like a listNode, and have in that listNode a reference to the Next node. Then a delete on the first node would go through to every single one.

Comment: -1, this doesn’t work – you’re confusing `List` and `ListNode` here. This won’t iterate through the list nodes.

Comment: Clearly each node saves the next node. So you can just iterate through the list. I don't get what you are trying to point here, with proper implementation this works. List object stores the first Node, and each node points to the next, so you can pass the delete from one node to the next.

Comment: The destructor of a node should not delete nodes it is connected to. If you tried to remove and delete a single node from a list you would end up deleting everything after it. A node doesn't "own" the next node, it simply connects to it - the `List` "owns" each node, and so the `List` should destroy them.